# Action bar buttons only showing in the overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I tried to add buttons with icons to the Action Bar so I followed the info on the android developer [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). However despite having assigned icons, the buttons will only be displayed in the overflow and not on the bar itself. I want the buttons to appear on the bar with their icons. My code:

The `onOptionsItemSelected` method of the activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_new:
        launchAddRuleActivity();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` of the activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The `main.xml` for the action bar layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.mhmt.autotextmate.Main" >

<!-- New, should appear as action button -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_new"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_new"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Lastly, the target and min SDKs:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

I got the drawables from [here](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) so the size shouldnt be a problem. This class does extend `ActionBarActivity`, and imports `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. I'm currently testing on a Google Nexus emulator running Android 5.1.1 with 720x1280 resolution.

I must be doing something wrong, can anyone see what I'm missing to display the buttons with their icons, and not in the overflow?

Comment: what happens if you use `android:showAsAction="always"`?

Comment: @Blackbelt I changed the showAsAction of the action_new to always, it's still in the overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this  `app:showAsAction="always"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.mhmt.autotextmate.Main" >

<!-- New, should appear as action button -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_new"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/action_new"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I also wont want the text, but only the icon to be displayed.

Comment: You must use "app" not "android".

Comment: Wow! I'm blind. Ty very much :)

Comment: I have the same problem but I have 12 items in the menu and If I put "always" never appear all the elements. And If I put ifRoom, it appears a strange icon as a overflow menu that I couldn't click and another icon in the button bar. Do you know what I do it to delete the strange icon?